# Use Tiebreaker having nan values while calculating the Rank in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, where there is a weighted score, and tiebreaker column. We have `NaN` values in tiebreaker column. The data frame looks like -

```
Name    Weighted_Score(%)   tie_breaker
   A    12.0    2.7
   B    13.0    2.8
   C    14.0    NaN
   D    14.0    3.2
```

Now i want to calculate the Rank based on weighted_Score(%), and if weighted_score(%) is same, then use Tie breaker.

In my case, following code is working fine until and unless there are no "NaN" values in tie_breaker column.

```
df['Rank'] = df[['Weighted_Score(%)', 'tie_breaker']].apply(tuple, axis=1).rank(method='dense', ascending=True, na_option='bottom').astype('int')
```

Above is giving the wrong Rank.

```
Name    Weighted_Score(%)   tie_breaker Rank
A   12.0    2.7 1
B   13.0    2.8 2
C   14.0    NaN 3
D   14.0    3.2 4
```

i tried converting the tiebreker nan values to 0.0, still nothing happening.

Comment: Can you provide the exact expected output for clarity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea to fillna was good, but you would need to use `np.inf` to ensure the NaNs are ranked last:

```
df['Rank'] = (df[['Weighted_Score(%)', 'tie_breaker']].fillna(np.inf)
              .apply(tuple, axis=1).rank(method='dense', ascending=True, na_option='bottom').astype('int')
             )
```

Output:

```
  Name  Weighted_Score(%)  tie_breaker  Rank
0    A               12.0          2.7     1
1    B               13.0          2.8     2
2    C               14.0          NaN     4
3    D               14.0          3.2     3
```

Alternatively, you could [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and `na_position='last'`, then increment a rank with [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
cols = ['Weighted_Score(%)', 'tie_breaker']
df['Rank'] = (~df[cols]
              .sort_values(by=cols, na_position='last')
              .duplicated()
             ).cumsum()
```

Comment: Thank you @mozway! you are always a savior.

Comment: @ggupta you're welcome, I added an alternative that doesn't require `apply`

Comment: that's a good option though. however, not sure if cumsum() will also give correct result when my data size is larger.

Comment: how to replace "inf" back to 0?

Comment: You don't need to replace it back to zero, if you followed my method the `fillna` should have been done temporarily on a copy and not be assigned to the original data

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the Rank based on `Weighted_Score(%)` with tiebreaker handling `NaN` values, you can create a custom ranking function. Here's how you can do it:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Sample DataFrame
data = {'Name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
        'Weighted_Score(%)': [12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 14.0],
        'tie_breaker': [2.7, 2.8, np.nan, 3.2]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Replace NaN values in the 'tie_breaker' column with a very low value (-np.inf) to ensure they rank lower.
df['tie_breaker'].fillna(-np.inf, inplace=True)

# Sort the DataFrame by 'Weighted_Score(%)' and 'tie_breaker' in ascending order.
df = df.sort_values(by=['Weighted_Score(%)', 'tie_breaker'], ascending=[False, False])

# Use the rank() method to calculate ranks with 'min' method to handle tiebreakers.
df['Rank'] = df['Weighted_Score(%)'].rank(method='min', ascending=False).astype(int)

print(df)
```

This code will correctly rank the rows based on `Weighted_Score(%)`, and in case of ties, it will use the `tie_breaker` values. It also handles `NaN` values by replacing them with a very low value, so they rank lower.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please back your answer with output obtained using OP's input data.

Comment: @OCa this answer looks like a typical ChatGPT answer

Comment: @Zeus Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please take a moment to read [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).  We do hope you'll become a valuable member of the community by posting *your own* quality answers and questions in the future.  Thanks!